# installshield 2012 save project on 64 bit

Tags: automation, 64-bit, installshield, wsh, installshield-2012

I have found a bug on InstallShield 2012 when running on a 64 bit machine, I get this error when I use SaveProject() from Automation Interface:
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe Abnormal program termination"

I have tried to run a vbs script preceeded by C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe and the error appears only when SaveProject() method is executed.

Can somebody give me a hint? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is full path of ism file is provided in the SaveProject() ?